# Bad quality video after watermarking with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
I'm using the following arguments to watermark a video with ffmpeg from a c# app:

> -i "video.AVI" -s 384x288 -vhook "vhook/imlib2.dll -x 0 -y 0 -i
>   "watermark.png"" -y "output.avi"
>   -sameq

The orginal file size is 233mb but the output is 60 odd mb. I thought using the -sameq argument would give me the same size and quality output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `-sameq` try defining the bitrates manually with `-ab` and `-vb`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I used -b myBitrate. Any idea how I calculate the bitrate programmatically?

Comment: If you know the length of the video (seconds) then it is `file size / video length`. - But if you plan to put them on a webserver there are some reasonable bitrates to use. For standard definition you can use 500kbps, but if you have such low resolution 320kbps sould be fine.