# ffmpeg - how to apply filters without losing quality

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is a simple request, it has an input, output, and two watermarks. From what I gathered I can't apply `-codec copy` because I'm using a filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i wm-bl.png -i wm-br.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y=H-h,overlay=x=W-w:y=H-h" output.mp4
```

This does the trick, as far as watermarking is concerned, but the output is compressed into half the original file size.

Is it possible to watermark without losing video quality?

Comment: Possible duplicates: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206445/bad-quality-video-after-watermarking-with-ffmpeg
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046031/ffmpeg-watermark-video-with-same-quality-and-filesize

Comment: Babblo, I'm aware of the other posts that don't answer my question. Brad, I listed and tagged it PHP in case somebody wanted to know what language I'm using so they could offer an alternative solution.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/buggedcom/phpvideotoolkit-v2 ?

Answer (score 17):

## You must re-encode to perform any filtering

Therefore any attempt at [stream copying](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) while filtering will be ignored. This is why `-codec copy` does nothing for you.

## Lossy, but looks lossless

Alternatively you can use proper encoding settings that look "visually lossless", but technically are not truly lossless. Example for H.264:

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -vf format=yuv420p out.mp4
```

- `-crf` controls quality: range is a log scale of 0-51, 0 is lossless, ~18 is often considered visually lossless, and 23 is default.
- `-preset` controls encoding speed and therefore compression efficiency: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium (the default), slow, slower, veryslow.
- `-vf format=yuv420p` uses a compatible chroma subsampling required by most players.

## Using a lossless format

Although you must re-encode for filtering it does not mean that you have to lose quality. You can use a lossless encoder, such as:

- `-codec:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow`
- `-codec:v ffv1`

**The output file size can be huge–generally much bigger than your input file.**

## Use CSS or your player to add the watermark

Avoid encoding completely and just deal with the watermark with CSS or with your HTML5 video player.

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: Thanks! Maybe add that re-encoding using a losless format might give you a bigger file than the one you started out with.

Comment: how to use this with filter_complex?

Comment: @Max `ffmpeg -i input -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -filter_complex format=yuv420p out.mp4`

Answer (score 2):

**In case anyone could benefit from it:**

I have been trying to find a solution to keep video quality after adding drawtext (has Same quality issue as adding filter) on Android (using FFMpegKit lib)

Adding -crf 0, -preset speed or any other common suggestions didn't help.

**Using the original video bitrate** have helped to solve it:

1. **get bitrate**:

val mediaInformation = FFprobeKit.getMediaInformation(input.path)

val **bitrate** = mediaInformation.mediaInformation.bitrate.toLong()/1000L

2. **add it to your FFmpeg command**:

"-y -i input.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 *(as example)* -b:v **${bitrate}k** -acodec copy -vp *(whatever filter)* output.mp4"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible when using the `overlay` filter (at least with FFmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 that I uses), even you use a lossless encoder for the final output file. Because the `overlay` filter itself uses a lossy encoding during the process, the image quality will certainly degrade after overlay; however this degradation usually won't be noticeable, and this filter is well suitable for most videos.

But if your input files are already in lossless formats, and if you absolutely want a lossless result, then don't use the `overlay` filter. I don't have a good solution for this, but here's my workaround.

- Extract the original video, frame by frame, into PNG files:

```
mkdir frames
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 frames/%d.png
```

- Add watermarks or anything you want to overlay onto the video; GraphicsMagick is used in this example:

```
for f in frames/*.png; do gm composite -geometry +0+640 wm-bl.png "$f" "$f"; gm composite -geometry +1100+640 wm-br.png "$f" "$f"; done
```

- Reassemble frames into a new video file, using a lossless encoding format; also remember to specify the same framerate as original video:

```sh
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i frames/%d.png -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv444p output.mp4
```

It is obvious that this workaround is very inefficient -- modifying a large number of PNG files one by one would take a very long time, especially the original video is long; storing these temporary PNG files will take a lot of space on the file system, and the progress would take even longer if the file system isn't fast enough on accessing that many files.

But it worked for me, I think sharing it may just help other people with a similar issue.

Comment: Per @PetrDiblík's answer, add :format=auto to the overlay command for lossless encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `format=auto` to the details of the `-filter_complex` parameter.

Or if the value `auto` isn't suitable in your case, try another - they are listed in the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#overlay-1) section of FFmpeg documentation.

See the specific example command in my comment of [Skinkie's answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/33743/34610) of my question "How to losslessly replace a specific area in a range of frames".

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an answer to this particular question.